# Dynamic Groovy Uploaded to Grails Application

Tags: grails, groovy, embedded-resource, groovyshell

**Yes, we're aware of all the security risks that come with the ability to upload code into a production system by users, but for the sake of this question let's pretend it doesn't matter.**

In a Grails application being developed we need to allow the user to upload some Groovy code that will be used by the Grails application as well as a CLI that our customers will download and use.

I am aware of the following [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) regarding embedding Groovy.

Is there a better alternative than embedding and interpreting on the fly?  Or is this pretty much it?

Comment: Alternative is asking users to compile and send compiled classes/jar, but i'm sure it's not what you want

Comment: I'm not against that.  If I were to go with that approach, how do I get that loaded into Tomcat's classloader? So the other parts of my app can see the byte code?

Comment: I was really thinking that you're making some script interpreter. Ok, classloading is more flexible (you can use plain Java, other jvm languages), but i'm not sure about using own classloader inside Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by embedding Groovy. The console plugin provides a fairly nice way of adding running code on the fly with access to the grails context and domain classes. http://grails.org/plugin/console . If you look into the code, it wouldn't be very hard to simply store scripts in your database as strings and use the script execution mechanism provided by the plugin.